# Why Has My Ubuntu Started Defaulting To Root User On Startup? (Duel Running Windows 10)

Tags: startup, root, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Hi

I have been using Ubuntu for a number of months.  I run a Windows 10 PC and installed Ubuntu via the Microsoft Store.  I created a user for myself during the initial setup - since then whenever I open an Ubuntu terminal from Windows it loads as that user.

On Thursday, I loaded Ubuntu and, instead of loading up as my user, it loaded up as the root user.  My user still exists - I can switch to my user via `su` and then proceed as normal.  It's not causing me any problems, but it does qualify for unusual behaviour and there are obvious security implications.

I have run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to make sure everything is up to date.  I am using the same Windows account to load Windows 10 that I always have.  I am not aware of any operational changes that have caused this behaviour.

One factor that may indicate a cause - I use `code .` to access Visual Studio Code.  This was not working after switching user, and was only made to work again when I added it to my user's $PATH.

Attempting to google this situation has been somewhat undermined by Google assuming I want to log in as root, where in reality the reverse is true.

Can anyone suggest what may be going on here, and suggest a fix please?  I'm not above ripping everything out and starting again with a fresh install, but before I entertain that I was wondering if something simple could be an issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu installation?  If so, please add the WSL tag.

Comment: *"This was not working after switching user, and was only made to work again when I added it to my user's $PATH."* Can you elaborate more on that?  I can probably suggest a fix without that info, but understanding that part may be relevant to figuring out the *why* behind it, since you (also) ask, *"Can anyone suggest what may be going on here...?*"  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and the output of `wsl -ll -v` might be useful - Not sure yet, but I can think of another possible cause that would be confirmed or refuted by that information.

Comment: Hi @NotTheDr01ds.  Yes of course.  

I usually open VSCode by typing `code .` as my user.  When Ubuntu started defaulting to root, `code .` still opened VSCode as root.  However, when switching to my user using `su`, the `code .` command failed with error `code: command not found`.  

I ran `echo $PATH` to find no mention of VSCode, and manually added it.  After this, my user was able to run `code .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I loaded Ubuntu and, instead of loading up as my user, it loaded up as the root user.
>
> Can anyone ... suggest a fix please?

Usually this means that the registry entry that tells WSL the UID for the default user has been "lost".  The typical solution is to tell WSL which UID it should use by creating a `/etc/wsl.conf` (as root) with the following:

```
[user]
default=your_username
```

Some other alternatives are mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).

> Can anyone suggest what may be going on here ...?

I was hoping I'd be at least able to theorize on a reason *why* this happened, but from our discussion in comments, I'm still not sure.

For a default Ubuntu installation under WSL, the default uid (typically 1000) is stored in the registry.  That information can be lost if:

- A WSL distribution is `--import`ed.
- Or if something else changes that would "disconnect" the registry entry from the distribution.  Renaming the default Windows' user's folder would cause this, but it would also cause the distribution itself to be "lost" (which isn't the case).

So it doesn't sound like either of those were the reason why the default user got changed.  However, if there is no default user set for a WSL distribution, uid 0 (root) is used instead.  Which is definitely what you are seeing.

You can see the registry entries for all your WSL distributions by running the following in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\
```

I'm guessing that either `DefaultUid` is missing or is set to `0`.  But again, not quite sure how this happened.

> My user still exists - I can switch to my user via `su` and then proceed as normal.

That's good.  At least we should be able to tell WSL to use it as the default again.

> It's not causing me any problems, but it does qualify for unusual behaviour and there are obvious security implications.

You might think, but defaulting to root, as mentioned above, is expected behavior in WSL.  There is no concept of "login" in a WSL distribution -- You can log in as any user using `wsl -u <username>` (e.g. `wsl -u root`) anyway.

The rationale given for this is that even root in WSL is limited to the permissions of the *Windows* user.  It doesn't matter if you are root or not, you still wouldn't be able to delete or change, for instance, a binary in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response!  I have made the `wsl.conf` changes and have seen a return to the desired behaviour that persists between sessions.  Thanks also for the clarity regarding how WSL regards logins.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4276#issuecomment-509338642

Open PowerShell as an administrator. Paste the command:

```bash
ubuntu2004.exe config --default-user <username you wish to switch to>
```

> Note: Replace the distro with the version on your system. For me, the version I have installed is ubuntu20.04. After that, launch Ubuntu.